# Outlook.com ICS / iCal url?

Tags: calendar, office365, outlook.com

How do you overlay a calendar from outlook.com to an office 365 company user calendar?

I cannot find a way to generate a link to an ical or ics file from outlook.com/Hotmail.com website.
Only think I can find on the outlook.com website on the Calendar view is the "Share" button to fill in the emailaddress of the O365 account. But I don't see a way to view the url or share the url in order to overlay it from internet source.

situation now:

- Calendar of O365 work account (accessible in Outlook 2016 app and via outlook.office.com o365 owa)
- Calendar of outlook.com personal account, accessible via www.outlook.com website

requested situation:

- Calendar of O365 work account + overlay of the outlook.com personal account. I want to be able to view the calendar of the personal outlook.com account as overlay in Outlook 2016 app and also in the outlook.office.com o365 owa site.

Any help is welcome. Most information is out-dated online.

I can't find how to do it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846807.aspx#sync

This is also outdated: https://mikebeach.org/2013/02/10/how-to-share-a-hotmail-calendar-using-ical/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the Outlook Beta first.

Go to Settings>Options>Calendar>Shared Calendars>Calendar Publishing and select Create (either show availability only or availability, titles, locations)

A html and ics link will pop up on your screen. Use the ics link to subscribe to your calendar from your O365 work account et voila! 
IMPORTANT: Remove the "s" from https in the link to avoid credential prompt when subscribing!

Note that this functionality is not available in the Outlook Beta. After you share the calendar you can revert to Beta if you wish.